# Deploy Hadoop to Openstack

Tags: deployment, hadoop, openstack

I'd like to deploy Hadoop to Openstack cloud. Is there any automatic way to do that?

Anyone tried to do that? I'm looking for some devops like juju. I've never used juju and right now I'm going through juju's tutorial about deploying, but most examples are based on Amazon's cloud.

Anything better than juju? I'd like to deploy Hadoop on Opensuse instances so juju is just temporary solution for me. right now it's not working, but I think I'll handle it sooner or later, but of course any tutorial would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

For an automatic deploy you'll need to dive into the world of Chef and Crowbar. Probably the best place to start is here.

http://robhirschfeld.com/2011/11/29/hadoop-crowbar-released-to-open-source

For a manual deploy, the folks over at Big Data Craft have implemented Hadoop on OpenStack’s Swift. You'll need to use their implementation of java-cloudfiles.

There is a blog post about it at http://bigdatacraft.com/archives/349

The code can be found here:

https://github.com/Dazo-org/hadoop-common

https://github.com/Dazo-org/java-cloudfiles

Answer (score 1):

Add the Sahara (OpenStack module) to OpenStack. It manages Hadoop for you.